# getting null pointer exception in face detection while defining the path of "\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"

Tags: java, opencv

```
public class FaceDetector {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        System.out.println("\nRunning FaceDetector");

        CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(FaceDetector.class.getResource("\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml").getPath());
        Mat image = Highgui.imread(FaceDetector.class.getResource("abc.jpg").getPath());

        MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);

        System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s faces", faceDetections.toArray().length));

        for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
            Core.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
                    new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
        }

        String filename = "ouput.png";
        System.out.println(String.format("Writing %s", filename));
        Highgui.imwrite(filename, image);
    }
}
```

This is my error image:

[image: error]

getting null point exception error. how to resolve I also try to give full path but same problem. please help me.

Comment: Have you solved this problem by using the absolute path?It didnt work for me

Comment: Didn't work for me either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass absolute path to `CascadeClassifier`. For example:

```
CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier("D:\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
```

And do the same for the image to read and write. This is wired but it is truth that in this case it can't read the files. Same was the case with me and I have solved.